# Failed compiling ocaml-websocket

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-batteries, ocsigen, ocaml-lwt

Trying to build ocaml-websocket, it fails with:

```
File "lib/websocket.ml", line 202, characters 29-42:
Error: The function applied to this argument has type
         ?buffer_size:int ->
         (Lwt_io.input_channel * Lwt_io.output_channel) Lwt.t
This argument cannot be applied with label ~setup_socket
```

The function line in question is,

```
lwt ic, oc = Lwt_io.open_connection ~setup_socket sockaddr in
```

Any idea, if the lwt API was changed in previous release?

Comment: https://github.com/vbmithr/ocaml-websocket/issues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used a customized version of Lwt, that’s why. I’m going to release a new version, compatible with normal Lwt, very soon.